# What is a deacon’s bench called in ecclesiastical circles in French?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

**What is a *deacon’s bench* called in ecclesiastical circles in French?**

I am interested in knowing if there is an ecclesiastical term in French as to what a **deacon’s bench** is called.

In American English a deacon’s bench is defined as follows:

> A kind of bench whose hinged seat is also the lid of an enclosed storage compartment. - [Source](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/deacon's_bench)

[image: Antique Deacon’s Bench]

[Antique Deacon’s Bench](https://www.pinterest.ca/romans3/deacons-bench/)

Is there an ecclesiastical term for this type of Church furniture in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it either *un banc à coffre* or *une chaire double à coffre*.

Examples:

[Banc coffre d'église](http://patrimoine.bzh/gertrude-diffusion/dossier/banc-coffre-d-eglise/6668059a-7cb7-456d-968e-1429fdc1f2b4/illustration/0)

[image]

[Chaire gothique](https://www.aguttes.com/lot/20583/4356892)

[image]

[Chaire double à coffre](https://www.rouillac.com/fr/lot-294-89330-chaire_double_coffre_chene._elle_est)
[image]

I also thought about *cathèdre* but *cathèdres* only allow a single person (the bishop) to sit.

Answer (score 2):

La description correspond aussi à celle de la [*stalle*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stalle), disposant d'un [*abattant*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abattant) :

> [...] sièges fixes en bois sculpté, à dossier élevé et à fond mobile,
>   séparés les uns des autres par des accotoirs communs, qui sont
>   disposés, sur deux ou trois rangées, de part et d'autre du chœur d'une
>   cathédrale ou d'une église abbatiale et sur lesquels les membres du
>   clergé prennent place pendant les offices.
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé (TLFi), « stalle » ]

Dans une [description](http://www.patrimoine-culturel.gouv.qc.ca/rpcq/detail.do?methode=consulter&id=213321&type=bien) d'un ensemble de stalles on dit par exemple « Deux stalles légèrement inclinées vers l'arrière, formant un siège à deux places [...] ». On n'est donc pas surpris de trouver *siège à deux places* comme traduction de *deacon's bench* de manière générique ([1](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18048888), [2](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=DEACONS%20BENCH&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) ; une source précise « de style colonial », ce qui rappelle une [définition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deacon%27s%20bench) un peu différente du terme en anglais, sans l'*abattant*. On est rendu un peu ailleurs cependant avec le siège à deux places du moderniste [Joan Busquets i Jané](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Joan_Busquets_i_Jan%C3%A9) de 1902, par exemple (voir [ici](https://unesdoc.unesco.org/ark:/48223/pf0000086457_fre), p. 36).